# Trying to write a script to change the end of file names with a .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have a bunch of files that I need to rename. They are variable length.  Like this:

```
A1B2C3D4.en.fr.pdf
A1B2C3D4S8.it.fr.pdf
A1B2C3.de.fr.pdf
A1B2C3D4E5.zn.fr.pdf
```

I want to change them so that I can run a .bat file to make 2 changes:
prefix them all with a static prefix, XYZ10;
replace the .*.fr.pdf variable ending with the static FRFR.pdf;.
So they'll look like this:

```
XYZ10A1B2C3D4FRFR.pdf
XYZ10A1B2C3D4S8FR.pdf
XYZ10A1B2C3FRFR.pdf
XYZ10A1B2C3D4E5FRFR.pdf
```

I've been doing it in individual steps each time with power shell but it's a pain to keep doing it and sometimes it does it improperly.

I've tried this:

```
@echo off
ren *.??.fr.pdf *.FRFR.pdf
```

but it just makes them look like this:

```
A1B2C3D4E5.zn.fr.FRFR.pdf
```

I don't know where to begin with the prefix, I don't really understand any of the things I've been reading about it...

EDIT:
This is what I've been doing to prefix in PowerShell.

> Dir *.pdf | rename-item -newname  {"XYZ10"+ $_.Name}

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%i in ('dir /b "*.??.fr.pdf"') do ren "%%~i.%%~j" "%%~iFRFR%%~xj"`

Comment: I would use a similar, more complete, and slightly more robust one liner, ```@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('"(Set PATHEXT=) & %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe ".":"*.??.fr.pdf" 2>NUL"') Do @For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do @For %%I In ("%%~nH") Do @Ren "%%G" "XYZ10%%~nIFRFR%%~xG"```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll look up the terms used in this so that I can understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple `ren` command line to rename as you desire (walk through the thorough post [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875)). I would do it the following way:

```cmd
rem // Loop through all relevant files:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%K in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.??.fr.pdf"') do (
    rem // `%%K` is the full file name, `%%~nK` has got `.pdf` removed, `%%~xK` is `.pdf`.
    for %%J in ("%%~nK") do for %%I in ("%%~nJ") do (
        rem // `%%~nJ` has got `.fr.pdf` removed, `%%~nI` has got `.??.fr.pdf` removed.
        rem // Actually rename the file (complaints in case of conflicts):
        ren "%%K" "XYZ10%%~nIFRFR%%~xK"
    )
)
```